# Python3: Correct way to define custom init error

Tags: python-3.x, exception

Suppose you have a custom class that has some required arguments (which you can not provide default values for) and you want to have a custom error that is raised when these required arguments are not provided.

What is the proper pythonic way to do this?

Right now I have something like this:

```
 class MyClassInitError(Exception):
     def __init__(self, missing_kwargs):
         self.message = "Some required key word arguments were not present {missing}".format(missing=missing_kwargs)

 class MyClass():
     # required arguments for this class that can not have pre-defined values
     _required_kwargs =  ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3",...]
     # required arugments for this class that can have pre-defined values
     _predef_kwargs = {"pre_arg1":1, "pre_arg2":2, ...}
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         try:
             # leverage set class to get keys of required args not in the passed kwargs
             missing_kwargs = list(set(self._required_kwargs)-set(kwargs.keys())) 
             if missing_kwargs:
                 raise MyClassInitError(missing_kwargs)

             # set defaults for defaults not provided
             for k, w in self._predef_kwargs.items():
                 if k not in kwargs.keys():
                     kwargs[k] = w
```

Comment: And is there a *problem* with that? If you want suggestions on improving **working code**, see [codereview.se].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am new to defining my own exceptions in python and don't quite see how this adds anything than just moving the print statement to where I raise the error and returning None afterwards... I will check out Code Review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) introduced syntax to require keyword arguments, so there is no need to write your own code to do the validation:

```
 def __init__(self, *, arg1, arg2, arg3, pre_arg1=1, pre_arg2=2):
     pass # TODO: use the args, no need to check them
```